# MVC image upload - Uploaded with incorrect orientation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, image-processing, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to MVC from webforms and I am trying to upload images to my azure storage container.  I have got the images to upload and resize as I want, however some images are being uploaded in the wrong orientation, e.g. they are being uploaded in landscape instead of portrait.

I have googled this but cannot seem to find anyone else having this issue.

My code I have to upload is as follows...

Thanks in advance

```
        string accountName = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        string accountKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

        try
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
                CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

                CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer = client.GetContainerReference("uploadedimages");
                sampleContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

                CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);

                using (Stream file1 = file.InputStream)
                {
                    WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
                    if (img.Width > 300)
                        img.Resize(300, 300);

                    byte[] bytes = img.GetBytes();

                    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                }

                string userIdValue = getUserId();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    YourDayEntities6 context = new YourDayEntities6();
                    context.CreateDayByDate(model.DayDate, blob.Uri.ToString(), model.DayDesc, userIdValue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error{0}", e.Message));
        }

        return RedirectToAction("GetAllDaysByDate");
```

Comment: Ok just to make sure I've asked the obvious question - you are sure they are not originally in the format they upload in ? How do you determine their original orientation - do you open them in an editor or just look at them in Explorer (some programs will reorient images to make them portrait or landscape based on the longest axis)

Comment: They look like they are portrait on my computer.  I have also tried uploading images from my phone camera, taken in portrait, stored in portrait on my phone, but then displayed in landscape when uploaded..

Comment: Thats probably not a good definition of "orientation". Try opening the image in a program like "Paint.net" (here http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) and look at the underlying width/height - Paint.net will open your image in its native format and will not attempt to re-orient it.

Comment: Are you using some Client (JS) library to manage de Uploads?

Comment: Azure storage itself has no knowledge whatsoever of what it's uploading, so it can't do something like rotate a picture. It just grabs the bytes as is and puts them in Azure. @PhillipH probably has the right idea to check the image source more carefully.

Comment: I've downloaded paint.net and my pictures are all in portrait mode.. still being uploaded in landscape though :(

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times I've seen this problem is not due to the Storage, Azure Storage will save the file bytes.

Image orientation is part of the [EXIF information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) which is included in the file binary.

If you are managing the uploads using a Client (JS) library, you can lookup in its documentation and see if maybe, the EXIF information is being erased or modified by it, some libraries have even methods to alter it.

There are some issues with images taken by phones which report a wrong EXIF information (Landscape instead of portrait or viceversa), to fix this scenario, you need to process the EXIF information prior to the upload. Some plugins that might fix this are [blueimp Javascript Load Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image), [ng-file-upload for AngularJS](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Comment: Right ok thank you i'll see if I can find any info on the EXIF info as mentioned above.  I am not using any JS library to upload, just using a file input control and the code above at the moment.